# NetfilterQueue Implementation

Tags: networking, netfilter

I am trying to use NetfilterQueue for my project. As a beginning, I tried to run this code. You know the source.

```
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue

def print_and_accept(pkt):
print pkt
pkt.accept()

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, print_and_accept)
try:
nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
print
```

I passed it the packets filtered by the following rule

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -s iitp.ac.in -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

I got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkt_desc_1.py", line 8, in <module>
    if nfqueue.bind(0, print_and_accept) < 0:
  File "netfilterqueue.pyx", line 144, in netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue.bind (netfilterqueue.c:2665)
OSError: Failed to create queue 1.
```

Can anybody help ?

I am new to the topic. So, please don't mind.

Comment: Are you running your python code as root? Also, the code shows you using queue 1 while the error message appears to be using queue 0. Which is the actual code in your python file?

Comment: Sorry for my typing error. It was supposed to be                                                               if nfqueue.bind(1, print_and_accept) < 0:. Anyway, now I have known the source of error. There was already a NFQUEUE linked withe above mentioned packet filter. When that program was running, I closed it using Ctrl-Z instead of Ctrl-C. So when I tried to run it again, I got the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 2):

identify process number (type)

```
ps aux | grep python
```

it will show processes in python

```
root      1633  0.0  0.4  16664  8680 pts/1    T    13:03   0:00 python netfilter.py
root      1687  0.0  0.0   6136   956 pts/0    S+   13:12   0:00 grep python
```

use kill process (type)

```
kill -9 1633
```

hope this helps =D